# Read a selected content in Property file using spring annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am having below property file in classpath "test.properties"

```
FR = PAR,Paris,France,ParisMetropolitan
IN = MAA,Chennai,India,Chennai International Airport
IN = BLR,Bangalore,India,Kempegowda International Airport 
SE = ARN,Stockholm,Stockholm-Arlanda Airport    
SE = BMA,Stockholm,Stockholm-Bromma Airport .
```

I want to read the above property file based on country code which is the first two characters.
example If country code is IN then I have to get the below details
IN = MAA,Chennai,India,Chennai International Airport.

Kindly help me how it can be achieved using spring  annotation @propertysource.
Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [example](http://websystique.com/spring/spring-propertysource-value-annotations-example/). This example pretty much has everything you need.
Hope it helps!